# iframe issue with IE8

Tags: html, iframe, internet-explorer-8

So I'm doing some work on a site to make it compatible for IE8 (Client request, don't ask). Now the website contains some videos in iframe tags which are displaying blank in IE8.

According to [Blank iFrame in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444014/blank-iframe-in-ie) I have to write 'position:relative' in order to show the video. Below is my full tag:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/whatever" frameborder="0" style="position:relative;" ></iframe>
```

This however, doesnt seem to work. Even with position:relative it still shows as blank.

The above 'Blank iFrame in IE' question is a number of years old so I'm wondering has there been any changes sinse HTML5 in how this should operate? Or should the code still work and I'm doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Now my IE8 working well after figure this out.. Firstly i have an experience like you do such as blank content.

So here the few step to fix this.

Try installing `shockwave player`.

After that on menu setting click `tools > manage add ons`

and `enable it the shockwave flash object`

[image]

Let me know the result. Regards.

[image]

Comment: ah right didnt think of that. The videos did seem to work in the end for some reason - they didn't show in the IE emulation but they did show when I actually ran the browser. Weird. But it works now. I appreciate the help though!